# AJAX Page Download progress

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to get the progress of my AJAX request - how much has been downloaded so far out of how much the file is. For example, I am downloading a large picture with AJAX so I can put the content in a DATA url (this may not be the best way to do that, it's just a example.)

So, I make the AJAX request to some host I have no control over (flickr), and report the progress back to the user. I cannot find a way to do this without a server-side script or something like that. Preferably the solution would use JQuery, because that is what I use for my website.
Thanks! Isaac

Comment: That *isn't* the best way to show picture download progress, so it would help to know what you **actually** want to do....

Comment: This [stackoverflow thread][1] discusses the same problem.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, the $.ajax() function has no support for "bytes loaded".  It only has start and complete events, no progress event.

I found [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/kmrpk7w3h56tidxs#query:jquery%20ajax%20download%20progress+page:1+mid:kmrpk7w3h56tidxs+state:results) detailing an attempt, but apparently the code works in several browsers but not IE.  The suggestion they make is to show progress in other browsers, and a simple "loading..." message for IE.

Do note that there are several similar discussions on the same site, so browse the left panel for other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Some browser provide support for download status events wher you can track your progress (i know ff 3.5+ does).

This is done by ajax XHR.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest) and [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/xhr-progress-and-richer-file-uploading-feedback/)

also, it is possible to split up a file in an array (let's say we divide it in 10 pieces),

now send 1peace, and return succes after, progress = 10% etc ...

Comment: But splitting the file is a very bad idea since handshakes take very long in HTTP.

Comment: Links are not an answer.