# Jquery:: Ajax powered progress bar?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I have a page which uses jquery's ajax functions to send some messages.

There could be upwards of 50k messages to send.

This can take some time obviously.

What I am looking to do is show a progress bar with the messages being sent.

The backend is PHP.

How can I do this?

---

My solution:
Send through a unique identifier in the original ajax call.
This identifier is stored in a database(or a file named with the identifier etc), along with the completion percentage.

This is updated as the original script proceeds.

a function is setup called `progress(ident)`

The function makes an ajax call to a script that reads the percentage.
the progressbar is updated
If the returned percentage is not 100,
the function sets a timeout that calls itself after 1 second.

Comment: Nice, great idea. I'm glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have an animated gif load via `.html()` into the results area until your ajax function returns back the results. Just an idea.

Regarding the jquery ui progress bar, intermittently through your script you'll want to echo a numeric value representing the percent complete as an assigned javascript variable. For example...

```
// text example php script
if (isset($_GET['twentyfive-percent'])) {
    sleep(2); // I used sleep() to simulate processing
    echo '$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 25 });';
    }
if (isset($_GET['fifty-percent'])) {
    sleep(2);
    echo '$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 50 });';
    }
if (isset($_GET['seventyfive-percent'])) {
    sleep(2);
    echo '$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 75 });';
    }
if (isset($_GET['onehundred-percent'])) {
    sleep(2);
    echo '$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 100 });';
    }
```

And below is the function I used to get the progress bar to update its position. A little nuts, I know.

```
avail_elem = 0;
function progress_bar() {
    progress_status = $('#progressbar').progressbar('value');
    progress_status_avail = ['twentyfive-percent', 'fifty-percent', 'seventyfive-percent', 'onehundred-percent'];
    if (progress_status != '100') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php?' + progress_status_avail[avail_elem],
            success: function(msg) {
                eval(msg);
                avail_elem++;
                progress_bar();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

If I had to guess, I bet there is a better way... But this is the way it worked for me when I tested it.

Comment: I may be going crazy, but is success not called only when the entire response is received?

Comment: Exactly, which is why I had to break up the php script into 4 different functions and make 4 ajax calls.

Answer (score 7):

Check this if you use jQuery:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

You can just supply the value of the bar on every AJAX success.

Otherwise, if you don't use JS Framework see this:
http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/

I don't have a way to test it, but it should go like this:

```
    var current = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var total_emails = <?php $total_emails ;?>; 

    $.ajax({

      ...
      success: function(data) {
        current++; // Add one to the current number of processed emails
        total = (current/total_emails)*100; // Get the percent of the processed emails
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", total); // Add the new value to the progress bar
      }
    });
```

And make sure that you'll include jQuery along with jQueryUI, and then to add the #progressbar container somewhere on the page.

I may have some errors though ...
You will probably have to round the total, especially if you have a lot of emails.

Comment: Yeah I will be using progress bar, The main part of my question is, How do I get the progress?

Answer (score 5):

[Use this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399641/ajax-page-download-progress)

this is how i implemented it:

```
    var progressTrigger;
    var progressElem = $('span#progressCounter');
    var resultsElem = $('span#results');
    var recordCount = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Granules.asmx/Search",
        data: "{wtk: '" + wkt + "', insideOnly: '" + properties.insideOnly + "', satellites: '" + satIds + "', startDate: '" + strDateFrom + "', endDate: '" + strDateTo + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            Map.LoadKML(xml);
        },
        beforeSend: function (thisXHR) {
            progressElem.html(" Waiting for response from server ...");
            ResultsWindow.LoadingStart();

            progressTrigger = setInterval(function () {
                if (thisXHR.readyState > 2) {
                    var totalBytes = thisXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-length');
                    var dlBytes = thisXHR.responseText.length;
                    (totalBytes > 0) ? progressElem.html("Downloading: " + Math.round((dlBytes / totalBytes) * 100) + "%") : "Downloading: " + progressElem.html(Math.round(dlBytes / 1024) + "K");
                }
            }, 200);


        },
        complete: function () {
            clearInterval(progressTrigger);
            progressElem.html("");
            resultsElem.html(recordCount);
            ResultsWindow.LoadingEnd();
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            var message = new ControlPanel.Message("<p>There was an error on search.</p><p>" + msg + "</p>", ControlPanel.Message.Type.ERROR);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it, since if you want the progress bar to measure the progress of a background process, you don't want to be hitting the server with multiple ajax requests... I'm going to test this method and see how well I can get it to work!