# How can I create an animated loading bar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery:: Ajax powered progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503658/jquery-ajax-powered-progress-bar)

I need to create some kind of countdown

**pleas in Html**

```
count = Math.floor((futureDate-today)/1000);

if(count > 0) //move Loading bar by percent
```

How can I have the same Loading bar of the code that has the animation of the battery?

[Like this demo](http://showcase.webdesignpla.net/supercharged/)
*and this is my [demo cod](http://jsfiddle.net/NfLAB/1/)e which I used to decrement the counter:*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a starting date as well in order to have a percentage for the battery. Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uhGjz/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>MyBattery</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
#bat {
    width:100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}
#fill {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 0%;
}
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
var now = new Date();
var today = now.getTime();
var pastDate = Date.parse("Tue, 1 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT");
var futureDate = Date.parse("Tue, 1 Aug 2012 00:00:00 GMT");
var count = Math.floor((today-pastDate)/(futureDate-pastDate)*100);

if(count > 0) { //move Loading bar by percent 
    $('#fill').animate({
       width: count+"%"
    }, 1000);
}

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="bat"><div id="fill"></div></div>
  <!-- Your own content! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My fraind this work with html5 i want the same code in html

Comment: The code posted above is JavaScript. As you can see in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhGjz/) you need to add the following HTML: `<div id="bat"><div id="fill"></div></div>` Good luck! And by the way, if you expect good answers on this board you need to vote or accept...

Comment: ya sorry I Accept your anser and thank youuuu for anser me

Comment: who can incloud this code in my page ??? just i copy this code and cod in (css and javascipt and this div='bat' )  to page html or deffrent way ??

Comment: See edit... But maybe you should check this place for some basic understanding on how to create websites ;-) Good luck again! http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: thhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhank you ^_^