# Progress bar in Django with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, progress-bar

I will try to make as clear as I can. I am trying to develop a progress bar in Django using Javascript. I have a list in python in which the progress will be stored like this in test variable:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', source12, destination], 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        test = sort(proc)
```

Here is a sort function:

```
def sort(rprogress):
    '''This function extracts the percentage from the rsync progress and return strings of percentanges'''
    progress1 = re.findall(r'\d+%', rprogress)
    remove_duplicate = set(progress1)     #Remove Duplicate percentage from list
    remove_percent = [a.replace('%', '') for a in remove_duplicate]     #Removes percentage
    sorted_list = sorted(remove_percent, key=int)     #Sort in ascending order
    return sorted_list
```

Now I want to use the list `test` and show the progress bar in the template. I am returning the list test as json:

```
return HttpResponse(result=simplejson.dumps(test), mimetype="application/json")
```

Upto this am I doing everything correctly? Now, I want to have a javascript that will listen to the variable and update the javascript variable and show the progress bar. What's the good place to start? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Jquery UI's ProgressBar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) could be an option worth looking at. You might also want to use [AJAX](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQFjAC&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/&ei=1kTQUO2NBcr_rAeNg4DYCA&usg=AFQjCNF1ITsE5bJBc65MY4nqhZq7OkHZpg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk) to send the updated value to the ProgressBar element.

Also, do look at these questions, they might help.

[Jquery:: Ajax powered progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503658/jquery-ajax-powered-progress-bar)

[AJAX Page Download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399641/ajax-page-download-progress)