# is there any alternative plugin of filedownload in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, download

I was trying to download a file using angularjs but at the same time i need to get status of download. for this scenario we have jquery.filedownload plugin in jquery but is there any plugin as filedownload in angular..?

could you help me on this.. thank you.

Comment: hope this may help you @Venkat ,http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971

Comment: Thank you @ThazAhammad but when i download the file i get a jar file. will that be enough..!? actually i need a plugin for frontend dev

Comment: @Thaz Ahammad I guess thats a intellij plugin. I guess what he meant in the question is a angularjs library for filedownload

Comment: yea @guru, is there an alternative for it in angularjs..!?

Comment: Dont know about any angularjs plugin. But have a look at his SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265917/javascript-source-file-download-progress
It has a sample implementation to track the progress using jquery.