# Is it possible to get the download complete event using JavaScript at client end?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, download, dom-events

I have a download link, which downloads a file say "down.exe" from some path say "://root/download/down.exe".

The "down.exe" is just placed at server path "/download/"

Is there any JavaScript methods, to get the download complete event in this case?

Or if I have do some other methods, please suggest me..

Comment: There is no JavaScript event for download complete. What is your goal? Perhaps there's a better method to achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks @jivings: i want to show download success message for user after download completes. Is there any better method??

Comment: may be this could help you with jquery [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265917/javascript-source-file-download-progress][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265917/javascript-source-file-download-progress

Answer (score 0):

Hey for downloading something you need complete postback of the page.You can try this and in PageLoad event of GenerateFile.aspx you can write your downloading code.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "GenerateFile.aspx;
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Can u brief a little. How you will trigger oncomplete event here??
onload seems not work here??