# How to get the progress status in the "status" column of a datatable using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, datatables

I'm able to connect to socket and get the data .But I'm unable to display the percent in the status column.

I'm getting this error : DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter 'null' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4.

How to resolve this issue...

Backend code:

```
io.of('/socket_issue').on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Socket connected :"+socket.id);

    });

var callback = function(state){
    console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
    console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
    console.log('percent', state.percent);

     io.of('/socket_issue').emit('message', JSON.stringify({size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: file_name}));

} 

progress(request('https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz'), {
    throttle:0,   
    delay: 0       
})
.on('progress', callback) 

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name))
.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log("error");  
})
.on('close', function (err){
console.log("Download Complete"); 
})
```

My code in template.html:

```
 {
     "sTitle": "Status",
      align: 'Center', 
      "mData": null, 
      "bSortable": false, 
      "sClass": "head1", 
      "sWidth": "55px",
      "render": socket.on( 'message',   function (data, type, row, meta) {
          console.log(data);//Here I'm able to get socket data
          var percentage = JSON.parse(data).percent;
          if (data.IsDirectory) {
              return percentage;
          }else{
              return percentage;
          }
       })

  }
  ]   


};
socket.on('disconnect', function(){})
```

My template.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>File Browser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="panelDiv">

           <div class="panel-heading">
                   <button type="button" id="butDiv" >Browse</button>
                    <input type="text" name="location" size="35"/>
                   <span class="up">
                    <i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> Up
                   </span> 
           </div>
      <div id="showDiv" class="panel-body">
              <table class="linksholder">
              </table>
      </div>

  </div> 
    <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/datatable/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/socket.js"></script>

<script>


        var extensionsMap = {
                      ".zip" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".gz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".bz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".xz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".rar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tgz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tbz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".7z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".mp3" : "fa-file-audio-o",         
                      ".cs" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".c++" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".cpp" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".js" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".xls" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".xlsx" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".png" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpeg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".gif" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".mpeg" : "fa-file-movie-o",         
                      ".pdf" : "fa-file-pdf-o",         
                      ".ppt" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".pptx" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".txt" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".log" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".doc" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                      ".docx" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                    };

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#showDiv").hide();

});  

$("#butDiv").click(function(){
        $("#showDiv").show();

 });


  function getFileIcon(ext) {
    return ( ext && extensionsMap[ext.toLowerCase()]) || 'fa-file-o';
  }


var socket = io('http://localhost:8089/socket_issue');
  socket.on('connect', function(){ console.log('connected to socket'); });
  socket.on('error', function(e){ console.log('error' + e); });



  var currentPath = null;
   var options = {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
         "sScrollY":"250px",
      "fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
    var path = aData.Path;
    $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
        $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
            table.fnClearTable();
            table.fnAddData(data);
            currentPath = path;
        });


        $.get('/directory?path='+ path).then(function(data){        
            $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);

         });         
    e.preventDefault();
    });
},


        "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"File Name", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
              } else {
                return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
              }
            }
          },
            {"sTitle":"Date",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                 return  data.Date;
             }else{
               return data.Date;

             } 
            }
          },


        {"sTitle":"Status",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render":socket.on( 'message',   function (data, type, row, meta) {

                    console.log(data);
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                 return "";
             }else{
               return "";

             }
            })

          }
        ]   


     };
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){})

  var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable(options);

  $.get('/files').then(function(data){
      table.fnClearTable();
      table.fnAddData(data);
  });

$.get('/directory').then(function(data){        
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
   $("#showDiv").hide();
});

$(".up").bind("click", function(e){
    if (!currentPath) return;
    var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var path =currentPath.substr(0, idx);
    $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnAddData(data);
        currentPath = path;
    });

$.get('/directory?path='+path).then(function(data){
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);

 });

});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can anyone please help me out ...

Comment: from which line do you get this error?

Comment: From this line : "render": socket.on( 'message',   function (data, type, row, meta) {

Comment: Show please your backend code, do you use `socket.send()` or `socket.emit()` ?

Comment: I had edited the backend code

Comment: By the way this is redundant: ` if (data.IsDirectory) {
              return percentage;
          }else{
              return percentage;
          }`

Comment: Yes it is redundant.How can I overcome this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look [here](http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4):

> Each cell in DataTables requests data, and when DataTables tries to obtain data for a cell and is unable to do so, it will trigger a warning, telling you that data is not available where it was expected to be. The warning message is:
>
> DataTables warning: `table id={id}` - Requested unknown parameter
>   '`{parameter}`' for row `{row-index}, column{column-index}`` where:
>
> `{id}` is replaced with the DOM id of the table that has triggered the
>   error `{parameter}` is the name of the data parameter DataTables is
>   requesting `{row-index}` is the DataTables internal row index
>   (`row().index()`) for the row that has triggered the error.
>   `{column-index}` is the column data index (`column().index()`) for the
>   column that has triggered the error. The column index information was
>   added in DataTables 1.10.10. So to break it down, DataTables has
>   requested data for a given row, of the `{parameter}` provided and there
>   is no data there, or it is null or undefined (DataTables doesn't know,
>   by default how to display these parameters - see below if your data
>   does contain these values).

You are getting this alert, because you are setting `null` value to `mData` property when you are building your databale. [Here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) is described what happens when `null` is set as the value:

> null - the sDefaultContent option will be used for the cell (null by default, so you will need to specify the default content you want - typically an empty string). This can be useful on generated columns such as edit / delete action columns.

So, to get rid of this alert you should set a `sDefaultContent` property:

```
aoColumns": [
      {
        "sTitle":"File Name", 
        "mData": null, 
        sDefaultContent: '',
        "bSortable": false, 
        "sClass": "head0", 
        "sWidth": "55px",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data.IsDirectory) {
            return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
          } else {
            return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          }
        }
      },
```

Keep in mind that you should to it for every column.

**PS:**
If you are using `.emit()` method to send data, you should pass an object as an argument. However, in the provided code you are passing a json string. if you want to send a string via socket, use `.send()` method:

```
io.of('/socket_issue').send('message', JSON.stringify({size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: file_name}));
```

But I would advise you to pass an object:

```
io.of('/socket_issue').emit('message', {size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: file_name});
```

In this case you should not use `JSON.parse(data)` on the front side, since it is not a string anymore. Change:

```
 var percentage = JSON.parse(data).percent;
```

To:

```
 var percentage = data.percent;
```

Comment: Actually I'm able to get the data in the console.Can we use "socket.on" function in middle of aocolumns of a datatable.Actually at this line I'm getting an error. "render": socket.on( 'message',   function (data, type, row, meta) {

Comment: Ok, I will be back in a an hour and take a look.