# How to display the percentage of file downloaded in the status column of a datatable using socket.io

Tags: socket.io, datatables

How can I get % in the status column of a datatable.I'm really stuck over here.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

```
socket.on( 'message', function( data ){
    console.log(data);
    var percentage = data.percent;
```

I have to insert percentage here, so that it will display in the % in status column of a datatable :

```
 {"sTitle":"Status",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "75px",
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  if (data.IsDirectory) {
                     return  "";
                 }else{
                   return "";

                 } 
                }
              }
```

My template.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>File Browser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="panelDiv">

           <div class="panel-heading">
                   <button type="button" id="butDiv" >Browse</button>
                    <input type="text" name="location" size="35"/>
                   <span class="up">
                    <i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> Up
                   </span> 
           </div>
      <div id="showDiv" class="panel-body" >
              <table class="linksholder">
              </table>
      </div>

  </div> 
    <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/datatable/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/socket.js"></script>

<script>


        var extensionsMap = {
                      ".zip" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".gz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".bz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".xz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".rar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tgz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tbz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".7z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".mp3" : "fa-file-audio-o",         
                      ".cs" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".c++" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".cpp" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".js" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".xls" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".xlsx" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".png" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpeg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".gif" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".mpeg" : "fa-file-movie-o",         
                      ".pdf" : "fa-file-pdf-o",         
                      ".ppt" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".pptx" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".txt" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".log" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".doc" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                      ".docx" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                    };

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#showDiv").hide();

});  

$("#butDiv").click(function(){
        $("#showDiv").show();

 });


  function getFileIcon(ext) {
    return ( ext && extensionsMap[ext.toLowerCase()]) || 'fa-file-o';
  }



  var currentPath = null;
   var options = {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
         "sScrollY":"250px",
      "fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
    var path = aData.Path;
    $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
        $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
            table.fnClearTable();
            table.fnAddData(data);
            currentPath = path;
        });


        $.get('/directory?path='+ path).then(function(data){        
            $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);

         });         
    e.preventDefault();
    });
},


        "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"File Name", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
              } else {
                return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
              }
            }
          },
            {"sTitle":"Date",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "75px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                 return  data.Date;
             }else{
               return data.Date;

             } 
            }
          },


        {"sTitle":"Status",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "75px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                 return  "";
             }else{
               return "";

             } 
            }
          }
        ]   


     };
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){})

  var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable(options);

  $.get('/files').then(function(data){
      table.fnClearTable();
      table.fnAddData(data);
  });

$.get('/directory').then(function(data){        
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
   $("#showDiv").hide();
});

$(".up").bind("click", function(e){
    if (!currentPath) return;
    var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var path =currentPath.substr(0, idx);
    $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnAddData(data);
        currentPath = path;
    });

$.get('/directory?path='+path).then(function(data){
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);

 });

});

var socket = io('http://localhost:8089/socket_issue');
  socket.on('connect', function(){ console.log('connected to socket'); });
  socket.on('error', function(e){ console.log('error' + e); });
socket.on( 'message', function( data ){
console.log(data);
var percentage = data.percent;

});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**How to use "socket.on" function in aoColumns of a datatable**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867577/how-to-use-socket-on-function-in-aocolumns-of-a-datatable) - please dont repeat questions, it is better to improve or elaborate your first question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the progress status in the "status" column of a datatable using socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865515/how-to-get-the-progress-status-in-the-status-column-of-a-datatable-using-socke)