# Possibilities of displaying percentage using php and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, select

Hai in my mysql database i have around 20,000 records. User will give input to get certain results on the screen. Now when user provides his input and clicks on submit, a GIF image which keeps circling till the result is displayed on screen.

But i would like to display percentage (Loading 10%) instead of GIF image. Usually users provide date rage to fetch data so query will select data between given date range. So please give me an idea how i can how the percentage to users

Thank You..

Comment: What is it that you have tried?

Comment: i tried for insert query like 100 / (num of insert rows) = percent. I passed this percent to javascript file to show the percentage. And it worked out for me. But i'm not getting an idea for select query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, I am assuming you are using just one AJAX request to the server that returns the data.

1: If you are only doing one ajax request, then the only state you can watch is the [AJAX requests state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344186/485048) and change the percentage based on that. The problem with this is there is a big percentage change in time of the request between sending the request and receiving the result from the server.

2: You could send multiple requests and somehow track where the data ended of the first request and go through only sending small amounts of data at a time. This has the problem that it is taxing on how many requests you have to make and you are better off just returning all the data once.

The server shouldn't take much time at all getting all the data together so long as your table is optimised. I am guessing your main problem is the response being large (>1MB).
Unless the data is only 20,000 rows, just try and cut down unnecessary data you are sending down and it should be quite a quick request.

By the looks of [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399641/ajax-page-download-progress) there is one way to check how many bytes have been download but it is not compatible with certain browsers.

You are probably best off just limiting the data you return and offering paging options to the user if their request returned more than X results.