# How to show page load in % before displaying page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Ok so for an introduction to my site im am gonna have a short animation play with a bunch of images fading in and out and then once the user clicks a button, the page fades out and loads the content in. Keep in mind i have a bunch of images being loaded. I want to know how to make a page loading bar with % before anything happens and the user isn't looking at a black screen with no pictures popping up. I have looked all over google and SO without an answer. Some questions like this don't have a clear answer and aren't explaining the methods they use. Thanks!

i want something like mega.co.nz loading bar.

Comment: This question has already been anwsered [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/how-exactly-does-megas-download-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399641/ajax-page-download-progress).

Comment: Looks like that site computes a ratio (files rec'd)/(files to get) and updates a sprite.  Check out the `jsl_progress()` function in secureboot.js and this sprite: https://eu.static.mega.co.nz/images/mega/loading-sprite.png