# Gmail like file upload with jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I would like to upload files just like google mail does. I would want to use jQuery and PHP to do it is there anyway of getting the progressbar etc.?

Here I added a video of how google does it. http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-04-02_1948.swf

No flash, no perl or cgi please..

I guess I can live without the progressbar now I am actually searching for information about jquery plugins or just what things I would need to look at

Comment: Just so you know, Google actually is using Flash in GMail to do that. If you right-click on the 'attach file' link, you'll notice its a transparent SWF. Also, there are ways of uploading files asynchronously using iFrames if you don't want to use Flash at all. Ajax just doesn't support binary data.

Comment: ok if gmail uses flash, so how do they do now to also support html5 file drag&drop ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is weird that people say that gmail doesn't use flash, when you can plainly see the swf file in the gmail interface. Try right clicking on "Attach a file". It is what allows the multiple uploads at once among other things.

Comment: this is dated 2010, is this still the same today?

Comment: They still use flash for file upload on Google Drive

Answer (score 7):

The easiest would be to use [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), it's a small button written in Flash, with all the hooks to drive it in JS.  Very easy to use and works well with PHP

but, if you really want it to be pure JS, you'll need some help from the server.  specifically, you'll need to start the upload, and periodically query the server about how's it going.  unfortunately, PHP upload handling doesn't get any notification until after the download finishes.  you'd have to replace it with something else.  there are a few pure JS uploaders that include sample Perl server code just because of that.

IOW: JS and PHP don't (fully) cut it.  either add flash to the client, or a better upload handler at the server.

Comment: Yes. If you can go with Flash. This will save you days of work.

Comment: SWFUpload is excellent, only problem is that there is no way how to degrade it gracefully when flash is not available without writing the js handling yourself. What they call graceful degradation is just displaying warning box and hiding the upload button...

Answer (score 4):

in my opinion an excellent article on this topic:
http://robertnyman.com/html5/fileapi-upload/fileapi-upload.html

unfortunately support is lacking for IE and Opera, but hopefully this will change.

Answer (score 3):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is another swf (sorry) upload button that uses jquery. Same idea as what Javier mentioned.

Comment: It is funny how people are starting to say sorry when referring to flash. I lived (barely) through the days where the flash splash page was the rage until someone happened across the statistic of how many people clicked "skip intro".

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't support reporting of upload progress directly. So there is no way of reading the upload status back. However, there is a [patch](http://pdoru.from.ro/) that might work. I haven't tried though.

Comment: PHP doesn't *easily* support upload progress. It is possible, but seriously not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

GMail uses Flash to upload the file in the background. [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) is an open source project that foes something similar.

Answer (score 1):

...gmail uses an iFrame that has style display:hidden;   then when you upload on the form, it then sends the iFrame to the upload url.  There is no flash involved at all. The only thing Google does with flash on Gmail is just making noises for chats. And you have to allow that in settings.  They don't really use flash too much just because it is pretty bad as far as memory and cpu usage.  Javascript can do anything flash can do (albiet with a lot more code in some cases)  but Javascript, in 99% of cases is much faster, and better memory-wise.

Comment: Are you running Linux? They don't serve the Flash uploader to Linux clients because of bugs in the Linux Flash player. SWFUpload, for example, has a known issue where it freezes browsers on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use PlUpload. It has support for a lot of types and is highly customizable. You can check out the demos on the website. On the homepage it also shows what it supports on the homepage and has a fallback mechanism.

http://www.plupload.com/

Edit: It is available as a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

SWFUpload is gud and compatible with all type of web applications

Answer (score 0):

About Ajax not supporting binary data while form submission.. there is a workaround; if you are jQuery then you can use this Form Plugin (from malsup) here at http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/. I have been using it for years...

Also plupload seems promising.. thumbs up for that ;) i must say its a bit bulky!!!

Comment: The code linked to from here seems to write to the binary data to a textarea, and then handle it specially on the backend. I haven't tried using it, though.

Comment: It seems so; but it works like a charm. I had used it extensively for a project for a while then. I applied it to send huge-sized HTML forms. must say - I am a satisfied open-customer of it. lol.

Answer (score 0):

In 2018, a website using plain JavaScript can upload files like Google Mail does for mail attachments.  A single click can bring up the web browser's file explorer dialog.  A separate Submit button is not needed to start the upload.  The trick is to use a hidden HTML `<input type="file">` element.

Example HTML and JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>File Upload</title>
  <!-- Demo a button to upload files from a local computer to a web server. -->
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="inputFileElement" multiple style="display:none">
  <button id="fileSelectButton">Select some files</button>

  <script>
    const fileSelectButton = document.getElementById("fileSelectButton");
    const inputFileElement = document.getElementById("inputFileElement");

    // When the user presses the upload button, simulate a click on the
    // hidden <input type="file"> element so the web browser will show its
    // file selection dialog.
    fileSelectButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (inputFileElement) {
        inputFileElement.click();
      }
    }, false);

    // When the user selects one or more files on the local host,
    // upload each file to the web server.
    inputFileElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
    function handleFiles() {
      const fileList = inputFileElement.files;
      const numFiles = fileList.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        const file = fileList[i];
        console.log("Starting to upload " + file.name);
        sendFile(file);
      }
    }

    // Asynchronously read and upload a file.
    function sendFile(file) {
      const uri ="serverUpload.php";
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const fd = new FormData();
      xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          console.log("Finished uploading: " + xhr.responseText); // handle response.
        }
      };
      fd.append('myFile', file);
      // Initiate a multipart/form-data upload
      xhr.send(fd);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['myFile'])) {
    // Example:
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name']);
    echo $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    exit;
}
?>
```

This works on Internet Explorer 11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Opera.
This example was derived from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

For a progress bar, see [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)