# Upload files like in GMail

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gmail like file upload with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710852/gmail-like-file-upload-with-jquery)

I am learning JQuery and would like to know if there are any ways by which we can implement file uploading functionality similar to that found in GMail for attachment (while composing mail) using JQuery?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710852/gmail-like-file-upload-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

GMail uses Flash to upload the file in the background. [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) is an open source project that foes something siliar.