# how to open file chooser that can choose multiple files in Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to be able to open a file chooser dialog, from which I will be able to choose more than one file from the same dircetory. Similarly to the behavior that 'add attachment to gmail' provides.
Only I don't need to upload the files immediately through Ajax. the files that I chosed can be uploaded later when pressing on the submit button of that dialog.

The technologies that are available for me are: 
html, javascript,, JQuery (only if it's really needed) JSP, java

Thanks

Comment: Is Flash not an option? I think the only alternative then is a Java applet (urgh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From previous research (and a quick Google search now), it appears that you can't do that solely with HTML/Javascript with one input selection.  However, there are lots of Flash uploaders that will let you do this.  But, since Flash is not one of your technologies listed, I'm not sure if you want to go that route...

Comment: So how am I capable of doing it through Gmail without any Flash??

Comment: @Spiderman GMail uses Flash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710852/gmail-like-file-upload-with-jquery

Comment: OK read the link that you added with the previuos stackoverflow question - that was really surprising but I think that it answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As simple as it gets - just add "multiple" to the input element...

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Internet Explorer. Firefox (and also chrome) implements a [multi-file selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.multiple) in HTML5.

You can checkout the following alternatives using JavaScript:

- [Upload multiple files](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/)
- [jQuery multiple upload plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)
- [Ajax file upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) (the best one in my opinion)

Comment: I tried the demonstartion in the blog of your first link. And I could only choose one file at a time in this filechooser, not more than that.

Comment: @Spiderman: Yes, you can select one file at a time. But try selecting a file, and then other. A list of files is created and you can submit them together.

Comment: Exaclty - my original question is how can I chose more than one file with one file-chooser dialog opening

Comment: This is not possible in internet explorer. My suggestion is use an alternative.

Comment: @Spiderman: see my edits, the last alternative (Ajax file upload) works great. I don't know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options that I can thinnk of:

- html5 `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />` (lots of examples out there)
- Flash ([swfupload](http://www.swfupload.org/) is a standard here)
- Silverlight
- Java

Comment: There are different issues with all of these techniques.