# how to show create PHP progress bar showing progress of file upload and data insertion into database

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload Progress Bar in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php)

guys, i need some help with this problem

I'm doing a file upload process where the source file is transfered to the server and then the data from it is inserted in to database.

i need to display progress bar which shows the progress from the time of file uploading to server till data inserted into the database from that uploaded file.

i find files uploading progress bar only for files uploading to server and progress bar not till data insertion.

thanks in advance !

Comment: Since Apache does not pass the request to the PHP interpreter until the entire request is received, how would PHP code know anything about the status of the upload?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so to write a progress bar you need to know what 100% of the file-size are. To know the file-size on server-side (with PHP which runs server-side), you first have to receive the whole file. But after receiving the file, it doesn't help you anymore, because then the upload would be finished.

Progress-Bars on file-uploads are often done with Flash, as you can detect the file-size client-side with ActionScript (Flash's scripting language).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with PHP. PHP is server side language. Better way to do that is to use a jquery and animate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with PHP. I'd use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To measure the progress of the SQL queryes, you can do the following:

- After uploading the file you can run some regexp on it to detrmine how many queries you'll have to run
- You can then register a counter in SESSION or similar where you know how many queries you have run
- Have an AJAX script call a PHP script that gives you the total number of queries and how many of them were executed.

There are some problems though. I don't know what kind of data format you have for the file, so I presumed that it's something that can be transformed in queries. Also, it might be faster run a single query instead of hundreads (for INSERT for example)