# How to Add a Progress Bar to a HTML File Upload Form

Tags: php, upload, progress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload Progress Bar in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php)

Hi guys,

I have an existing HTML form which is used to upload a file, as well as other information which is written to an XML file for each upload. Someone else wrote this script and Im relatively inexperienced with php so I cant really use a plugin to replace the file input section, because the php gives the uploaded file a special name which is required in another process.

I am running IIS 7 with php 5.3. I have tried to install APC PECL extension though this does not work (have tried to use apache but it wont even start when APC is enabled). I have also tried the uploadprogress extension but this doesn't work.

Can anyone help me modify my existing form so that it shows the upload progress?

Many Thanks
Alex

Comment: see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/session_upload_progress and http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/151-Upload-Progress-in-PHP-trunk.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=progress+bar+php

Answer (score 0):

You can not display upload status with help of PHP.

PHP-Script are interpreted on server side, but uploading is transfer, so server doesn't know anything about upload and how much it still remaining.

You can use flash-uploader to get more controll about uploading process.