# how to get progress status of a file-upload

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload Progress Bar in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php)

forgive me if this is a stupid question but im only 15 and I just cant seem to find the answer on the internet.

how can i query the a server for status information of a file upload using php/js? I would use jquery for callbacks if necessary. I am trying to get the **upload progress** to build a little display bar.

Comment: Please see [Session Upload Progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) which is what PHP offers to obtain progress for a file-upload.

Comment: If you're 15 and posting on SO, keep going and stick with the programming as much as you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the progress on the server, and have another script return it.

I think thats the only option since uploading a file is a header request, and the page wouldn't be able to send back headers until the file was finished uploading.