# Progress bar and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

There is a way to get a progress bar that interfaces with a jquery ajax?
I ask this because i followed this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) to build an ajax upload with jquery, and it would be useful to see the progress of the upload.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery [UI has a progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) built in; it's very straightforward.

If jQuery UI isn't your thing, you could go for a straight plugin [like this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryProgressBar).

As for the process of determining how much of the file has been uploaded, that's a whole bag of trouble :)

[Here's an implementation](http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/) you can simply download and use, or pick apart for ideas. It employs APC, which shouldn't be too hard to get up and working.

Here's [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php) showing how to do it with PHP and no external libs; looks very promising.