# How can I get uploading ratio for file upload progress bar (idea not plugin)

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

I'm trying to create file upload using iframe(ajax effect) but I need to know how can I get uploading ratio while uploading file.
I found many plug-ins but I need idea or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this post, you will have pretty detail idea how realtime file upload works

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/FileUploadWithProgrss.aspx

Comment: Please mark the answer as 'Accepted' (by click on the tick) for other people know the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a very similar question posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php) That returns http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ as an example.

Due to its simplicity I'd also add this other one http://devpro.it/upload_progress/ they are both in php/javascript but I'm sure you can adapt it to your language of choice.

In general accurate upload report progress is a hard problem that requires server side support. Google for example offers a nice API for querying the reported progress. An example can be found on their original blog post

http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/2008/01/easily-upload-your-documents-to-google.html.