# Progress bar in my form without APC

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

My problem is that I don't know how to make a progress bar in my form which is the follow:

```
<form action="?do=up" method="post" class="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>
    <p><?= LANG_TITEL_CARD ?></p><p><input type="text" name="titel" size="65" /></p>
    <p><?= LANG_Card_Description ?></p><p><textarea rows="5" name="DESCRIPTION" cols="50" /></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="UP" />
</form>
```

How can I do it without using APC?

Answer (score 0):

The web is plenty of well-done progress bar. Google is your friend in searching this kind of stuff. Just a few results (I used the second and it works well):

- http://css-tricks.com/8518-css3-progress-bars/
- http://cssglobe.com/post/1468/pure-css-animated-progress-bar
- http://www.webappers.com/progressBar/
- http://encodable.com/filechucker/
- [Upload Progress Bar in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php)

Comment: I searched at google And I'm looking for a month ago ,But did not find anything useful.  I want a progress bar in my upload form and i have a input type of text When completed the upload send a Results to Databes.  ...Appreciating your consideration and cooperation