# Progress bar for a PHP upload

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload Progress Bar in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php)

I have been researching this with no success.

I have a php script which uploads a picture to Facebook. On the main page I want to show a button or a link or an image which starts a progress bar and runs the upload script at background.

Here is the upload.php file:

```php
<?php 

include_once 'facebook.php';
include_once 'config.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
'fileUpload' => true,
));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');

$FILE = "images/$uid.jpg";//the file is already stored   

$args = array('message' => 'Check yours on: http://apps.facebook.com/dec-death');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/photos', 'post', $args);

echo 'Picture has been uploaded';

?>
```

Comment: Can you please look at the right block titled "Related"?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with these you tagged! alternatively you can make an ajax call. so before ajax call you will start animation and on end you will hide/complete the animation!

Comment: English please, guys. This is an international community.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call your upload script via AJAX (Asynchronously) , and get the upload status during the upload to present a progress bar. There are great jQuery plugins already doing that such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

As one already commented here, this was asked so many times - So please next time just search before posting.

Comment: Please do not sign your posts.