# Simplest PHP Upload Progress Bar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, progress-bar

I have been looking for AGES trying to find a progress bar i can easily integrate without having to downloads libraries like APC etc.

Does anyone know a really simple PHP progress bar i can integrate with ease into my current code?

Massive Thanks!!!

Comment: lots on google and the one you sent me

Comment: You said you had been looking for 'AGES' and you didn't even check Stack Overflow..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php

Comment: I meant if you tried to write and use some code not if you tried to google it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You need to search inside JS plug-ins not PHP. That's why you did't find anything: there is no "progress-bar for PHP".

Instead, there are bunch of free jQuery (especially Ajax based) upload plugins. Here are some of them

http://www.uploadify.com/

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a true (server side) progress bar, you will have to install the libraries you mentioned.

You can however fake it, if the client knows how large the file is and how much it has transferred already.

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is one with multiple engines (HTML5, Flash, Silverlight etc.) and is being integrated via jquery

Answer (score 0):

This would be one http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

It doesn't require APC or any other external PHP libraries and you can get file progress feedback on a shared host.