# add functionality layer to AtTask by plug-in on Internet Explorer

Tags: plugins, internet-explorer-8, layer, attask

I would like to add functionality to the AtTask system by "adding a layer".
What I want to know is whether this can be achieved with a plug-in for Internet Explorer.

To give a concrete example:
This extra layer would allow users to click on "Online Edit" document (which is not available right now). The linked application will open, and when you click save, the file is loaded back to AtTask.
All this happens in the background via the AtTask API, and is transparent to the user.

The question is: is it possible to add functionality to a site by somehow adding layers?
Last comment: this plug-in (or whatever needs to be installed inbto the browser) will only be visible/active when accesing the AtTask website.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Within the confines of AtTask your best bet is to use an "External Page" create a service that handles the data in the manner you need.

The Dashboard that contains your External Page can be added as a tab via Layout Templates.

Most of the heavy lifting would have to be handled by your application. You would have to link the document(s) you wish to edit.

Some sort of referrer would be necessary to place the revised document back into AtTask. The method in which the client can do this would be determined by your preference and requirements. I am sure you can find some sort of **[Wiz-Bang jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477135/simple-cross-browser-jquery-php-file-upload-with-progress-bar)** uploader.

Depending on the level of control you have with your user base, you could make an Application URL

**Windows** : [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)
**OS X** : [Launching Scripts from Webpage Links](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/)

Comment: Thanks Steve. I was aware of the External page functionality in AtTask. The problem with that is that we want the user to see the new functionality on the same screen as the documents. By using the an External Page, the user will need to click on a dashboard to access the functionality...do you know of any way that can allow us to add a layer to what the browser shows to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any other way to handle this other than what Steve suggested.

Having said that a possible solution to this is to create a new application and iframe in AtTask.

At the top or wherever on the page your application could have a link for "Online Edit". Then you would use javascript to extract the task id, project id or any other needed information you need for the api to get the needed content to edit. Then save using the same api information.

I have not tried this type of method but theoretically it could work.