# Add a progressbar to form

Tags: javascript, html

Hi. What is the best way to add a progress bar to this form?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<center><p> <input type='file' size='58' style='height: 30px; font-size: 18px' name='filename'></p>
<input type='image' src='<?php echo $menu_upload_button; ?>'>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code writing service. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: i am not asking you to make any code, simply a direction like 99miles answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload Progress Bar in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php)

Comment: @kevin de groof, your question is not worded that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the jQuery progress bar http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Progressbar