# file is not uploading in jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

index.html is:

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" action="UploadHandler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">           
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" title='Click to add Files'>
<input type="hidden" id="fileCnt" name="fileCnt" value="">
<input type="submit" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" class="buttonsub" value="Upload Files">
</form>
<script>
$('#fileupload').submit(function(e){
//window.location='assays.php';
var target = 'windowFormTarget';
window.open('', target, 'width=500,height=300');
this.setAttribute('target', target);
});
</script>
```

UploadHandler.php:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Size(in bytes)</th>
<th>Status</th>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$_POST['fileCnt'];$i++)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$i].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$_FILES['files']['size'][$i].'</td>';
if($_FILES['files']['error'][$i] == 0)
{
    //print"<pre>";print_r($_FILES);die;
    //echo '<br/>'.$new_file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);die;
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="name-<?php echo $i;?>" id="name-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo trim($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tmp_name-<?php echo $i;?>" id="tmp_name-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo trim($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]);?>"/>
    <td>
        <div class="progress" id="done-<?php echo $i;?>">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
            Done
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="progress" id="wait-<?php echo $i;?>">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
            Uploading..
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php }
}
?>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var fileCnt = <?php echo $_POST['fileCnt']; ?>;
var j=0;
var files =<?php echo json_encode($_FILES);?>;
function doAjax(j,fileCnt) {
$("#wait-"+j).show();
$("#done-"+j).hide();
var name = $('#name-'+j).val();
var tmp_name = $('#tmp_name-'+j).val();
alert("#done-"+j);
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "postdata.php",        
       data: {                  
                'files':files,
                'id':j,
                'form_action': 'uploadFileData'
             },
        enctype:'multipart/form-data',
        success: function($succ){
                alert("result-"+$succ);
                if($succ == 1){
                $("#wait-"+j).hide();
                $("#done-"+j).show();                   
                }
                j++;
                if (j < fileCnt) {
                    doAjax(j,fileCnt);
                }
            }
    }); 
}
doAjax(j,fileCnt);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my postdata.php is:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
        {
            $new_file_name = trim($_POST['files']['files']['name'][$_POST['id']]);
            $tmp_name = trim($_POST['files']['files']['tmp_name'][$_POST['id']]);
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'uploads/'.$new_file_name))
            {
                echo "1";die;
            }else{
                echo "0";die;
            }
        }
```

UploadHandler.php opens up in a new window when user submits a form on index.html. And on load event of uploadhandler.php, ajax request for multiple files in a loop sends out for uploading the files to a directory.
Now the problem is that files are not uploading and i a not able to debug the problem.

Please help.

Comment: What I can see from you code, you submit the files to a second script that prints out some input-fields containing the files names (and tmp-names) and then tries to submit those to the server. If that is your intention: this will not work. The javascript may have access to name and tmp-name, but not to the files (which are on the server). What are you trying to accomplish in general?

Comment: Exactly I am trying to do the same. Yes i am doing all this to show the progress bars on second script until the file is not uploaded to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you are doing: I'm sorry, but that can never work.

As said, the javascript in UploadHandler.php may have access to the file names (and even tmp-names) but not to the actual file.

The UploadHandler.php script receives the files (in `$_FILES`). That is, the server software puts the uploaded files into some temporary directory with some random filename (this filename is in `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]`). The script can handle the file. An important thing to do, is to move the file. The script starts writing the html-output and sends it to the browser. Then, the script is finished and the server will make sure that everyting is cleaned up. That means: the uploaded files are deleted! (That's why you should move them, to prevent that).

For a good understanding of how file upload works, it may be good to read up again on the matter at [this php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). [The section on 'POST method uploads'](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) actually explains things quite well.

If you really want a progress bar, it is advisable to make use of some external library. [This question and answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php) will probably get you up to speed.

Also note that file upload via ajax is not very well supported yet, see also [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/2286722).

Answer (score 0):

Well, well, well. Small mistake. Isn't it `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST["files"]`? You need to change these lines:

```
$new_file_name = trim($_POST['files']['files']['name'][$_POST['id']]);
$tmp_name = trim($_POST['files']['files']['tmp_name'][$_POST['id']]);
```

Change them to:

```
$new_file_name = trim($_FILES['files'][$_POST['id']]['name']);
$tmp_name = trim($_FILES['files'][$_POST['id']]['files']['tmp_name']);
```

Also, the `[$_POST['id']]` should come before `["name"]` and `["tmp_name"]`.

Comment: But my $_FILES[] array is empty. No data received in it on postdata.php

Comment: @D.k The only way PHP can access file system is through `$_FILES`. No other way PHP can access. And you haven't provided your JavaScript code that sends the file to the server yet. It should be an AJAX call.

Comment: ajax call is in UploadHandler.php. Please scroll it down

Comment: @D.k It would be great if you could format the question.