# XMLHttpRequest progress updates on chrome need to be more granular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, web

I'm working on an uploader for angular-js that can give me progress updates.  The code below works however on chrome, for files that are under around 3MB, one progress update fires before it starts sending, and the event data indicates that all the bytes are uploaded.  It then takes some time (up to 30secs) before the file data is actually sent (and no further progress events will fire during the actual upload).  If I use a larger file, I'll get two events or maybe three.  On firefox, I'll get around 6 progress events for a 2MB file.  Does anyone know if there's a way to adjust the granularity of these updates to fix this.  To me, this function is basically useless (on chrome) since most documents aren't that big.  Thanks.

```
send: function() {
    var document = {
        DocumentName: this.fsEntry.file.name
    };

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', this.fsEntry.file);
    formdata.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(document));

    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.addEventListener("loadstart", this.onLoadStart, false);
    this.xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", this.onProgress, false);
    this.xhr.addEventListener("load", this.onComplete, false);
    this.xhr.open("POST", this.fsEntry.uploadUri, true);
    this.xhr.send(formdata);
}

this.onProgress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log("progress: uploaded " + e.loaded + " of " + e.total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest onprogress interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495625/xmlhttprequest-onprogress-interval)