# server progress indicator using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, progress

I've got a service accessed via HTTP on the server that is fairly long-running.  I need a way to display the progress in the web browser while the XMLHttpRequest is in progress.  I am trying to use the "progress" event, however the event never fires until the transfer is complete.

On the server side, I set the `Content-Length` header correctly, and then every second I send out a single byte to indicate progress.  (This is just for testing.  The idea is the actual process would send out one byte for every percent of progress.)  On the client side I am setting up the `progress` event on the XMLHttpRequest, with the intent to see how many bytes have been received which will also be the percentage done.  (100 bytes sent = 100% done)

If I connect to the server directly (e.g. telnet) I see it outputting a byte every 1 second.  But in the web browser, I do not get any progress events until the entire transfer is done!  A comment on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495625/xmlhttprequest-onprogress-interval) suggested that the browser wouldn't start sending progress events until at least 69 bytes had been received, so for good measure I sent 100 bytes at the start.  Yet, I still get no events.

Update: If I send 1000 bytes at the start I also don't get any progress events.  But if I send 10000 bytes I do get events for almost every additional byte sent.  Since the spec (as per the linked question) seems to suggest nowhere near this many bytes should be required, I'm a bit concerned as to whether I can rely on this to work across various browsers and platforms.

Comment: Not certain if `progress` event is dispatched based on response from server, but on data transmitted.

Comment: @guest271314 Wow. That linked question was so long-winded I didn't even manage to make it halfway through before giving up trying to figure out what it was trying to ask.

Comment: @guest271314 Also, had trouble parsing your comment... but my understanding is that progress event is dispatched by on data received from the server, and I am tailoring the server's response such that the amount of data received is proportional to the amount of server progress made.

Comment: @Micheal _"before giving up trying to figure out what it was trying to ask"_ Real-time communication between language-agnostic server implementation at server and  `EventSource` at browser. At the Question, a `File` object is uploaded. Progress of the write of the file at server is streamed to client (browser).

Comment: Am not aware if any browser natively implements progress events of "download" from server. Though could be incorrect, here, as to previous sentence.