# XMLHttpRequest 2 download progress event only firing once

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest-level2

I'm trying to get the progress of an ajax request via the following code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {

    console.log(event.loaded / event.total);
},
false);

xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {

    console.log('load');
},
false);


xhr.open('get', 'test.php', true);
xhr.send();
```

The problem is, the progress event only fires once, right before the load event (that is, in Webkit, it doesn't seem to work under Gecko).

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not supported properly?

Comment: Are you testing in localhost?

Comment: Yes but the remote host gives the same result.

Comment: Maybe this does help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @Fabian The answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest/3694435#3694435 relies on PHP's readfile. I can't use that because I expect to receive an HTML image element as responseText instead of raw image data.

Comment: Just make sure your webserver is configured to send the content-length header.

Comment: @Gerben Checked the ajax request in Firebug and the content-length header is set.

Comment: That is all the PHP does. So the script should just work. How large is your test file, and are you  testing locally? It could just be that it is loaded before the browser is willing to send a progress event.

Comment: How big is the response? If it's tiny, it's possible that it simply loads so fast.

Comment: Will test again with a couple of megabytes.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) { ... });
```

(note the added `.upload`)

Comment: The OP said "DOWNLOAD" in the question, your answer would provide information on the upload portion