# How to listen for the http request by A html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I use an `<a>` element to download a file in HTML page.
It takes some seconds, so I want to show a loading by listening to the http response.

Is there a way to show loading when clicked `<a>` element, and close loading when download completed?

This is what I want:

```html
<a href="https://..." download>download file</a>
```

Comment: I think you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793756/4051471)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress Bar (Download) Using HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993192/progress-bar-download-using-html-5)

Comment: @Justinas But i can't download a file by XMLHTTPRequest.I checked some solutions on stackoverflow.like:
[download-file.js](https://gist.github.com/zynick/12bae6dbc76f6aacedf0).
So,do i need to send a XMLHttprequest first, then use [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a URL?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways :

1. Use **ajax** for listening event or receive data from Back-end :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/getData", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
```

2. In addition , you can use socket.io to listen event from Back-end .

**At server send event :**

```
socket.emit('sendData', 'Your Data');
```

**At client listen event :**

```
 socket.on('sendData', function(data) {
        console.log(data); // Your Data
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequest provides the ability to listen to various events that can occur while the request is being processed. Beneath those also is `progress`
It checks if the amount of data that has been retrieved has changed.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);

oReq.open("GET", url);

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
       // DO your Stuff here
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}
```

> Note: You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the
>   request. Otherwise the progress events will not fire.