# Extjs file upload progress

Tags: forms, extjs, upload, progress

I have seen form file upload example in ExtJS4 and i need customize progress of the file upload.

I see waitMsg config property, but i don't want use that and i don't want use extjs 3rd party plugins.

So, how i can get simply current upload progress from upload form in extjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The waitMsg uses a message box with an infinitely auto-updating progress bar. So you can't just create a progressbar that displays the current upload.

You could create your own [`Ext.ProgressBar`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar) and *estimate* the upload time and when its done you set it to the max value. But I guess you don't want that.

To answer your question: You **cannot** simply track the current upload progress.

---

If you really need this user experience you can try a [3rd party component](http://blog.debug.cz/2012/05/file-upload-widget-for-extjs-4x.html).

---

To quote the docs:

> File uploads are not performed using normal "Ajax" techniques, that is
>   they are not performed using XMLHttpRequests. Instead the form is
>   submitted in the standard manner with the DOM  element
>   temporarily modified to have its target set to refer to a dynamically
>   generated, hidden  which is inserted into the document but
>   removed after the return data has been gathered.

Comment: i thinking extjs handles file PUT request and xhr must return bytes to sent... No?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest   this question about XHR discussed here. How i can get request xhr object from extjs?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wish we could do it easily ;)

Comment: We can send a request to Sencha :-)

Comment: Check 3rd party File upload widget for Ext JS v4.x by Ivan Novakov (https://github.com/ivan-novakov/extjs-upload-widget); and the same forked widget for Ext JS v5.x edited by Bugs Bunny (https://github.com/BugsBunny338/extjs-upload-widget).

Answer (score 1):

To show real progress you can use onprogress callback of XMLHttpRequest:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.request.Ajax, {
    openRequest: function (options) {
        var xhr = this.callParent(arguments);
        if (options.progress) {
            xhr.upload.onprogress = options.progress;
        }
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

Then use like here:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/upload/files',
    rawData: data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': null }, //to use content type of FormData
    progress: function (e) {
        console.log('progress', e.loaded / e.total);
    }
});
```

See online demo [here](https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-ajax-multi-file-upload-with-progress-bar.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Upload',
    handler: function () {
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        if (form.isValid()) {
            form.submit({
                url: '/upload/file',
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                success: function (f, a) {
                    var result = a.result,
                        data = result.data,
                        name = data.name,
                        size = data.size,
                        message = Ext.String.format('<b>Message:</b> {0}<br>' +
                            '<b>FileName:</b> {1}<br>' +
                            '<b>FileSize:</b> {2} bytes',
                            result.msg, name, size);

                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', message);
                },
                failure: function (f, a) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', a.result.msg);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]
```

Live demo with progress window is [here](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-upload-to-asp-net-mvc-demo.html)