# d3 csv parser on progress value

Tags: javascript, csv, load, d3.js, progress

So I'm trying to load a csv file in javascript using d3 and trying use a progress bar to show the progress it has made while loading. This is what I have:

```
d3.csv("my.csv",function(data){
        //do stuff with data
    }).on("progress", function(p){
        //update progress bar
        console.log(d3.event.loaded);
    });
```

and this is all that it outputs:

```
13248560
```

This is the total number of bytes in the file. I'd like to know how to get the value that it has loaded so that my progress bar could load appropriately. Anybody know how to accomplish this task?

Comment: If your browser has cached the CSV file, then typically you'll only get one progress event as the file loads very quickly from memory. If you want to test your code to display loading progress, you might want to use a cache-breaking query string for testing (e.g., "?" + Math.random()). But remember to remove it when you're done testing!

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is normal that the event `d3.event.loaded` returns the total size. Did you try the following to get the progress from the variable `p` in the function on `"progress"`?

Then to get the actual progress, you can use the following question: [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)

The final result should look like something like this:

```
d3.csv("my.csv",function(data){
        //do stuff with data
    }).on("progress", function(event){
        //update progress bar
        if (d3.event.lengthComputable) {
          var percentComplete = Math.round(d3.event.loaded * 100 / d3.event.total);
          console.log(percentComplete);
       }
    }
});
```