# jQuery progress bar and calculate submit proses

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is possible to submit the data (not the upload form) through ajax form to display a progress bar of the process?
The process is calculated from the progress bar calculation process that occurs on the server side and displayed to the progress bar ?

Comment: It is possible, googling for this gives plethora of results, is there anything in particular that troubles you about the use case scenario or?

Comment: I've tried browsing for the answer, but still have not found a similar case .. Can you help me give tutorial link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest - the process is similar to monitoring the file upload. Browser updates the xmlhttprequest object every 50 milliseconds and you listen to the `progress` event on that object.