# Progress bar while uploading large files with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload some large files to the server using XMLHttpRequest and file.slice.
 
I've manage doing this with the help of documentations and other various links. 
Since uploading large file is a lengthily job, i would like to provide the user with a progress bar.
After some more readings i've come across on an [example](https://github.com/mailopl/html5-xhr2-chunked-file-upload-slice/blob/master/index.html) that, theoretically, does exactly what i need. 
By taking the sample code and adapting it to my needs i reached

```
var upload =
{
blobs: [],
pageName: '',
bytesPerChunk: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
currentChunk: 0,
loaded: 0,
total: 0,
file: null,
fileName: "",

uploadChunk: function (blob, fileName, fileType) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.responseText) {
                // alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
        $("#dvProgressPrcent").html("100%");
        $get('dvProgress').style.width = '100%';
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var progress = Math.ceil(((upload.loaded + evt.loaded) / upload.total) * 100);
            $("#dvProgressPrcent").html(progress + "%");
            $get('dvProgress').style.width = progress + '%';
        }
    }, false);

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var progress = Math.ceil(((upload.loaded + evt.loaded) / upload.total) * 100);
            $("#dvProgressPrcent").html(progress + "%");
            $get('dvProgress').style.width = progress + '%';
        }
    }, false);

    xhr.open('POST', upload.pageName, false);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", fileType);
    xhr.send(blob);
},
upload: function (file) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var size = file.size;

    var date = new Date();
    upload.fileName = date.format("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss") + "_" + file.name;

    upload.loaded = 0;
    upload.total = file.size;

    while (start < size) {
        end = start + upload.bytesPerChunk;
        if (end > size) {
            end = size;
        }

        var blob = file.slice(start, end);
        upload.uploadChunk(blob, upload.fileName, file.type);
        start = end;
        upload.loaded += start;
    }

    return upload.fileName;
}
};
```

The call is like (without the validations)

```
upload.upload(document.getElementById("#upload").files[0]);
```

My problem is that the progress event doesn't trigger. 
I've tried xhr.addEventListener and with xhr.upload.addEventListener (each at a time and both at a time) for the progress event but it never triggers. The onreadystatechange and load events trigger just fine.

I would greatly appreciate help with what i am doing wrong

**Update**
After many attempts i've manage to simulate a progress but i've ran into another problem: Chrome's UI is not updating during the upload.
The code looks like this now

```
var upload =
{
    pageName: '',
    bytesPerChunk: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0,
    file: null,
    fileName: "",

    uploadFile: function () {
        var size = upload.file.size;

        if (upload.loaded > size) return;

        var end = upload.loaded + upload.bytesPerChunk;
        if (end > size) { end = size; }

        var blob = upload.file.slice(upload.loaded, end);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', upload.pageName, false);

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", upload.fileName);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", upload.file.type);

        xhr.send(blob);

        upload.loaded += upload.bytesPerChunk;

        setTimeout(upload.updateProgress, 100);
        setTimeout(upload.uploadFile, 100);
    },
    upload: function (file) {
        upload.file = file;

        var date = new Date();
        upload.fileName = date.format("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss") + "_" + file.name;

        upload.loaded = 0;
        upload.total = file.size;

        setTimeout(upload.uploadFile, 100);


        return upload.fileName;
    },
    updateProgress: function () {
        var progress = Math.ceil(((upload.loaded) / upload.total) * 100);
        if (progress > 100) progress = 100;

        $("#dvProgressPrcent").html(progress + "%");
        $get('dvProgress').style.width = progress + '%';
    }
};
```

**Update 2**
I've managed to fix it and simulate a progress bar that works in chrome too.
i've updated previous code sample with the one that works.
You can make the bar 'refresh' more often by reducing the size of the chunk uploaded at a time
Tahnk you for your help

Comment: Are you using a function to shorten `document.getElementById` calls? It looks like that's what `$get()` is doing, but I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: yes. but i don't think that is the problem. it work just fine in the load event and sets it to 100%

Comment: @Cioby could you upload a JSFiddle of your solution?

Answer (score 8):

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694435/460368, you could do :

```
if(xhr.upload)
     xhr.upload.onprogress=upload.updateProgress;
```

and

```
updateProgress: function updateProgress(evt) 
{
   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
       var progress = Math.ceil(((upload.loaded + evt.loaded) / upload.total) * 100);
       $("#dvProgressPrcent").html(progress + "%");
       $get('dvProgress').style.width = progress + '%';
   }
}
```

Comment: the progress event is still not triggered;

Comment: @Cioby Did you try doing it the asynchronous way? `xhr.open('POST', upload.pageName, true);` http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've tried both suggestions but without success. for reasons that i do not understand the progress event doesn't trigger. i've updated the main post with the progress

Comment: @Cioby did you attach `upload.onprocess` Before `.open('POST', uri, true)`?

Comment: [@Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35634/henry), thanks for the tip, putting the event handler before the open and send made it work.

Answer (score 5):

There is my solution:

```
function addImages(id) {
  var files = $("#files").prop("files");
  var file = files[loopGallery];
  var cList = files.length;

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", file);
  fd.append("galerie", id);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "moduls/galerie/uploadimages.php", true);
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    var percentComplete = Math.ceil((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    $("#progress").css("display","");
    $("#progressText").text((loopGallery+1)+" z "+cList);
    $("#progressBar").css("width",percentComplete+"%");
  };

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
      $("#progressObsah").load("moduls/galerie/showimages.php?ids="+id);
      if((loopGallery+1) == cList) {
        loopGallery = 0;
      } else {
        $("#progressBar").css("width", "0%");  
        loopGallery++;
        addImages(id);
      }
    }
  }

  if(cList > 0) {
    xhr.send(fd);
  }
}
```