# React Native and XMLHttpRequest - Upload Progress bar

Tags: react-native, upload, xmlhttprequest, base64

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to upload **images** to my server in a post request and the images are **in base64 format**. I looked all over the web and found that i can add a "progress" event to the upload. but it only fires when upload is complete... how can I get upload progress for such request in react-native?

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){}); // first attempt, not working...
http.addEventListener("progress", function(e){}); //second attempt, not working...


http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

http.send(params);
```

The answers mentioned in [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)
don't work. My guess is that react-native requires a different solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: tried everything that's mentioned there but its not working. seems to me to be related to react native but i don't really know.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet.
The only progress i got was that it does work on iOS. but doesnt fire on android.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965651/progress-bar-while-uploading-large-files-with-xmlhttprequest