# Get upload progress of individual files with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest (with jQuery) to get the upload progress of multiple files. By adding a "progress" event listener to the XMLHttpRequest object I can get `event.loaded` and `event.total`. Those variables give me the loaded and total bytes of all the files combined.

What I'd like to do is get the progress of each individual file, but from what I can see that information isn't available with XMLHttpRequest. Is that true?

I don't think this is even necessary, but here's my code:

```
var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
if (xhr.upload) {
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
        var percent = 0;
        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
        var total = event.total;
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
        }
        updateProgressBar(percent);
    }, false);
}
return xhr;
```

If I can accomplish this with XMLHttpRequest that would be great. Any info on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Thanks, but my script already does that. What I mean is I want the progress for each individual file, not all the files as a group.

Comment: Then only send one file per request.

Comment: It appears as though the $.ajaxSettings.xhr() object is global. You're not creating a unique instance of it, so how will it know which file you're referring to?

Comment: @Gavin you will have to run `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` **for each file you want to upload**. That is the only way to get individual `progress` events for the files. The `progress` event is related to the full XMLHttpRequest, it doesn't know or care about how many different "parts" or "files" are being uploaded; To the XHR, it's just binary. So to be able to know the progress of individual files you must only include a single file per request.

Comment: Thanks for that, idbehold. I was thinking about this method before, however I want to use a multiple file input, so they can select more than one file with a single file input. Due to browser security, I can't transfer the selected files each into their own dynamically created file input and create a request for each file. Using multiple ajax requests seems like it will only work if I have multiple file inputs in the HTML, one for each file, instead of a single multiple file input, right?

Comment: @idbehold you are totally correct. No way to show progress for each file in a single bulk upload.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use,

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        myXhr.addEventListener('progress', function (e) { }, false);
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                var completed = 0;
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var done = e.position || e.loaded,
                        total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                    completed = Math.round((done / total * 1000) / 10);
                }
                console.log(completed); // Displays the completed percentage
            }
        }
        return myXhr;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript plugin [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).
He handle file one by one, display progress bar for each files, easy to integrate, support mobile, drag-and-drop, ...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.dropzonejs.com/new-js/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dropzonejs.com/css/dropzone.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dropzonejs.com/css/style.css" />

<form action="/page_where_upload" class="dropzone">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
```

> If you try to run the snippet, you will get an server error because *page_where_upload* don't exist!