# How to use eventHandlers and uploadEvntHandlers with angularjs 1 http requests?

Tags: angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

I tried this code with no success

```
$http({
    method:"GET",
    url:"data/mycooljsonfile.json",
    eventHandlers:{
        onprogress:function(event){
        console.log("progress");
        console.log(event);
    },onreadystatechange:function(event){
        console.log("change");
        console.log(event);
    }
    },
    uploadEventHandlers:{
         onprogress:function(object){
              console.log(object);
         }
    }
})
.success(function(json){ // succès
     $scope.lemmes=json;
      //console.log($http);
}).error(function(error){ // erreur
    console.log(error);
});
```

I checked here :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

and there :

https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#events

It is just that I would like to improve my code with a progress bar on a big json file download to the app.

By the way, I could not find a way to log the overall $http object's functions and supported events as it returns a promise object with few info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3694435/949476

Comment: I know it is possible to do it in pure javascript, my question is about using Angular JS version 1, it is in the title.

Comment: Scratching around this for a few days now. No events fired :(

Comment: Drat . Found the solution. Update to angularjs 1.5.5 :D

Comment: Great, wish I could participate to the docs if I could. @SSR Can I have a link to a use case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227694/how-to-track-progress-using-eventhandlers-and-uploadeventhandlers-in-angularjs-1

Comment: My answer to this query was deleted on account of being same across few same queries :D . you can also refer - https://github.com/shuyu/angular-material-fileinput/issues/33

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `onprogress`, use just `progress`, same with other events. I prepare a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6f96WLfhwnGcG6gJSbOS) to demonstrate:

```
  $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "data.json",
      eventHandlers: {
        progress: function(event) {
          console.log("progress");
          console.log(event);
        },
        readystatechange: function(event) {
          console.log("change");
          console.log(event);
        }
      },
      uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function(object) {
          console.log(object);
        }
      }
    })
    .success(function(json) { // succès
      $scope.lemmes = json;
      //console.log($http);
    }).error(function(error) { // erreur
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Also, there was a bug that has been fixed in angular 1.5.5 as it can be seen from the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Update to the 1.5.5 or higher and it will work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try this in my free time. Cheers.

Comment: @mantisse accept it with a green tick and I will get some karma